# Page refresh with onclick event in dojo and I don't want a page refresh

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, javascript-framework

For some reason in IE8 when I run this function after an onclick event it causes a page refresh. I don't wan the page refresh to happen.

```
   var edealsButton = dojo.byId("edeals_button");
   var edealEmailInput = dojo.byId("edeals_email");
   var edealsSignup = dojo.byId("edeals_signup");
   var edealsThankYou = dojo.byId("edeals_thankyou");
   var currentValue = dojo.attr(edealEmailInput, 'value');
   if (currentValue != '' && currentValue != 'Enter your email') {
       var anim = dojox.fx.flip({
           node: edealsSignup,
           dir: "right",
           duration: 300
       })
       dojo.connect(anim, "onEnd", this, function() {
           edealsSignup.style.display = "none";
           edealsThankYou.style.display = "block";
       })
       dojo.connect(anim, "onBegin", this, function() {

           var criteria = { "emailAddress": '"' + currentValue + '"' };
           alert("currentValue " + currentValue);
           var d = essentials.CallWebserviceMethod('AlmondForms.asmx/SignupEdeal', criteria);
           d.addCallback(function(response) {
               var obj = dojo.fromJson(response);
               alert(obj.d);
               if (obj != null && obj.d != null) {
                   //alert(obj.d);
                   if (obj.d == false)
                   {
                       var edealSuccess = dojo.byId("edeals_succes_thankyou");
                       var edealError = dojo.byId("edeals_error_thankyou");

                       alert("edealError: " + edealError);
                       dojo.style(edealSuccess, "display", "none");
                       dojo.style(edealError, "display", "inline-block");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       var edealSuccess = dojo.byId("edeals_succes_thankyou");
                       var edealError = dojo.byId("edeals_error_thankyou");

                       dojo.style(edealSuccess, "display","inline-block");
                       dojo.style(edealError, "display", "none");
                   }
               }
               else {
                   var edealSuccess = dojo.byId("edeals_succes_thankyou");
                   var edealError = dojo.byId("edeals_error_thankyou");

                   dojo.style(edealSuccess, "display", "none");
                   dojo.style(edealError, "display", "inline-block");
               }
           });
       })
       anim.play();
       edealEmailInput.innerHTML == 'Enter your email';
   } 
   else 
   {
       dojo.attr(edealEmailInput, 'value', 'Enter your email');
       dojo.style(edealEmailInput, 'color', '#CC2525');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "d.addCallback" code might not be disposed of properly. You might want to try placing "dojo.stopEvent()" possibly before the "anim.play();" line and see if this would stop the postback.

From the [api.dojotoolkit.org](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.stopEvent) site, the dojo.stopEvent() "prevents propagation and clobbers the default action of the passed event". From the [docs.dojocampus.org](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/events) site, they say that "dojo.stopEvent(event) will prevent both default behavior any any propagation (bubbling) of an event."

Good luck, and hope this helps you out some.

Comment: I was missing the dojo.stopEvent(evt) and therefore the page was running the dojo and then doing a refresh as if a form button was pressed.

The dojo.stopEvent(evt) prevented the page from doing it's page refresh on a form submit button.